# LESS classes and elements nesting

Tags: html, css, less

this is my html

```
<div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="javascript:;">Best</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;">Bussiness</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;">First</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
<div>
```

and this is my less that does not work

```
.tabs {
    ul {
        li {
            list-style: none;
            float: left;
            background-color: #eee;
            padding: 8px 12px 8px 12px;
            border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
            border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
            border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 5px;

             &.active {
                border-left: solid 1px #999;
                border-right: solid 1px #999;
                border-top: solid 1px #999;
                background-color: #999;
                color: #fff;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my less that is working

```
.tabs {
    ul {
        li {
            list-style: none;
            float: left;
            background-color: #eee;
            padding: 8px 12px 8px 12px;
            border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
            border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
            border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
    } }


.tabs {
    ul {
        li {
            &.active {
                border-left: solid 1px #999;
                border-right: solid 1px #999;
                border-top: solid 1px #999;
                background-color: #999;
                color: #fff;
            }
        }
    } }
```

i have faced this issue many time in other cases and i can cee that the css being generated is the same

help please

and i have tried making it like this

i have made it like this

```
.tabs {
    ul {
        li {

            &.active {
                border-left: solid 1px #999;
                border-right: solid 1px #999;
                border-top: solid 1px #999;
                background-color: #999;
                color: #fff;
            }




            list-style: none;
            float: left;
            background-color: #eee;
            padding: 8px 12px 8px 12px;
            border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
            border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
            border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
    }
}
```

and the rules not applying too

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? It doesn't compile?

Comment: the css rules do not apply to elements

Comment: it seems to be working for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LAHrf

Comment: what verion of LESS are you running. JS, dotless, phpless, pythonless (joking) .. what, which version & how are you using it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try moving it up instead of down? Does it work like that?

Also, on a side note, replace `javascript:;` with `javascript:void(0)` or something.

**Update:**

The first example does work

http://jsbin.com/oxekih/1/edit

Try updating your DotLess NuGet package if your are using DotLess.

Comment: i have made it like this

Comment: i agree this what is happening with me it is not working in my website but when i try it on JSBIN or similar it works

Comment: Check the rest of the file for errors, paste the entire LESS file in JsBin, also check in chrome dev tools to ensure it's not just overriden or something, also,ensure you have the latest LESS, either JS version or dotLESS

Comment: i have checked chrome and it is not overridden like in the matched section the rules is not there

Comment: OK, check the rest of the file in JSBin, and check you have the latest version of LESS. Also, restart IIS, recompile project, etc.

Comment: iis, dotless, compile ? i don't see him mentioning those things anywhere. I'm almost sure he's using the JS version of LESS and running into some kind of recursion problem.

Comment: @Robert Well, let's say I have some insight context that makes me put these possibilities. I worked with him at the same client before, and if he is doing this at that client, then those possibilities might be valid.

Comment: i'm not using less compile i'm using less in side VS and it is generating the css for me and in the View Source screen i can see my css rendered fine